# Issue trying to solve Project Euler #1

Tags: c#

I'm having a problem trying to make a small app to solve [Project Euler Problem #1](http://projecteuler.net/problem=1).

Whenever I attempt to run this, it returns as 0, instead of 233168.

I'm not necessarily looking for an absolute answer, just some hints, I'm trying to learn.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x;
            List<int> listOne = new List<int>();
            for (x = 1; x < 1000; ++x)
            {
                if(x%3 == 0 || x%5 == 0)
                {
                    listOne.Add(x);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(listOne.Sum());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MD.Unicorn haha, sorry, I didn't mean to overwrite your formatting edits. I was mid edit when you put yours in :/ I'll roll it into a new one.

Comment: I'm really sorry about the bad formatting, I'll remember that for my next post. Thank you for those tips as well!

Comment: @user2264393 It wasn't that bad, we were just tidying it up for future people who might also be having issues with Problem #1 :)

Comment: Not formatting the code properly will lead to such a mistakes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interests of helping you learn, I'm not going to provide the exact answer.

Have a look at the scoping of your `Console.WriteLine()` statement. My guess is that it's not running when you think it should be.

Comment: Wow, you're right, I'm not sure how I looked over that. Thank you! It's returning much too large of a number now, but I will try and figure that one out.